# Only one model plugin receiving subscription data

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey guys,
I am publishing a Vector3 through a world plugin.

This is the code that publishes

```
namespace gazebo
{
    class global_wind : public WorldPlugin
    {
        ignition::math::Vector3d wind;
        transport::PublisherPtr pub;
        private: event::ConnectionPtr updateConnection;

        public: void Load(physics::WorldPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/)
        {
            gazebo::transport::NodePtr node(new gazebo::transport::Node);
            node->Init(_parent->GetName());

            transport::run();

            pub = node->Advertise<gazebo::msgs::Vector3d>("~/global_wind");

            this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(std::bind(&global_wind::OnUpdate, this));

        //  gazebo::transport::fini();
        }

        public: void OnUpdate()
        {
            // pub->WaitForConnection();

            wind.Set(2,2,0);

            gazebo::msgs::Vector3d msg;
            gazebo::msgs::Set(&msg, wind);

            pub->Publish(msg);
        }
    };
    GZ_REGISTER_WORLD_PLUGIN(global_wind)
}
```

The lines that are commented are causing some problems. The first commented line causes the following error

```
[Err] [ConnectionManager.cc:611] ConnectionManager is not initialized
[Err] [TransportIface.cc:416] ConnectionManager has not been initialized!
[Err] [Node.cc:125] No namespaces found
```

The 2nd commented line just makes gazebo hang when launching. Nonetheless, the plugin 'works' when these 2 are commented.

This is the code that sunscribes.

```
class wind_push : public ModelPlugin
  {
    // Pointer to the model
    private: physics::ModelPtr model;

    // Pointer to the update event connection
    private: event::ConnectionPtr updateConnection;

    math::Vector3 force;

    public: void Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
    {
      // Store the pointer to the model
      this->model = _parent;
      
      // Create our node for communication
      gazebo::transport::NodePtr node(new gazebo::transport::Node());
      node->Init();

      sub = node->Subscribe("/gazebo/default/global_wind", &wind_push::publ, this);

      gazebo::physics::LinkPtr link= model->GetChildLink("link_1");
      link->AddForce(gazebo::math::Vector3(20, 20, 0));

      // Listen to the update event. This event is broadcast every
      // simulation iteration.
      this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateBegin(std::bind(&wind_push::OnUpdate, this));
    }

    // Called by the world update start event
    public: void OnUpdate()
    {      
      gazebo::physics::LinkPtr link= model->GetChildLink("link_1");
      link->AddForce(force);
    }  

    public: void publ(ConstVector3dPtr &_msg)
    {
      std::cout << this->model->GetName();
      force.Set(_msg->x(),_msg->y(),_msg->z());    
    }  
  };    
  // Register this plugin with the simulator
  GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(wind_push)
}
```

So what's happening here is that I have many models with the above model plugin. The global_wind plugin publishes a global topic, from which wind_push is supposed to get the wind force vector and apply a suitable force. The problem is that only one model is responding to this force. After further debugging, I found out that only the model plugin on THAT model is calling the callback in the subscriber function, while I actually want all of them to be called. Debugging also revealed that all the model plugins are running, executing other parts of the code. I don't understand why this is happening. Thanks!

Edit:I printed the &wind_push::publ variable in the load function, and all model plugins referred to the same address! Shouldn't gazebo be running a seperate instance of the plugin for each model? Another thing I noticed is that the model which responds to the wind is the last model described with the subscriber plugin in the world file. I think that only the last model plugin's callback is being called. Or there's only one callback???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19431/only-one-model-plugin-receiving-subscription-data/) by [varunvp](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4457/varunvp/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Some ideas:

1. Use the fully qualified topic name on both the publisher and the subscriber (i.e. `/gazebo/default/global_wind`)
2. Did you try printing `this` instead of `&wind_push::publ` to see if that's also the same?
3. Why do you want to call `gazebo::transport::fini()` on your load function? That will finish the whole transport system, so no more pub/sub for anyone.
4. While running the simulation, run `gz topic -i /gazebo/default/global_wind` to see how many subscribers and publishers are there
5. Store your subscriber in a member variable, otherwise it will only live in the scope of the load function.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [varunvp](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4457/varunvp/) on 2018-05-24**:
Apologies for the delay.
The 1st solution worked for me! Thank you!

Edit:Nope, it was actaully the last solution that worked for me. I reverted to the earlier topic name. Also, I did store the subscriber in a member variable, but it was initialised outside the class. Don't know why I did that. It worked when I added it inside.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-05-24**:
Glad to hear it worked out